# How to make shallow copy of array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsmutablearray, shallow-copy

I have searched for a while but couldn't find reasonable answer for this. I want to add/remove objects in one array to make effect in 2nd array which points to first array.

```
class Person
{
    var name:String = ""
}

var arr1:[Person] = [Person]()

let p1 = Person()
p1.name = "Umair"

let p2 = Person()
p2.name = "Ali"

arr1.append(p1)
arr1.append(p2)
var arr2 = arr1

print("\(arr1.count)")    //"2\n"
print("\(arr2.count)")    //"2\n"

arr1.removeFirst()

print("\(arr1.count)")    //"1\n"
print("\(arr2.count)")    //"2\n"
```

Why changing arr1 does not affect arr2. Please help me out to accomplish this.

Comment: Your assignment `var arr2 = arr1` is in fact a lazy value copy of `arr1` to `arr2`, which takes effect only when either of the two arrays are mutated. If you really want to track one array with _same references_, you'd have to look into Swift unsafe pointers, which I would avoid. An alternative (safe but with overhead, possibly negligible) is to use some custom property observer on changes in `arr1`, and delegate the changes also to `arr2`. Alternatively, look into [Swift reactive/binding/observing API:s](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/ReactiveKit), allowing you to bind two properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays are value types. When we copy them, each copy is independent of the other. This is a virtue in Swift. What you are trying to do requires references so that effects on one can be seen by others. Try this code. Create a class (reference type) containing your data. Now changes to the container can be seen in the other.

```
class Person
{
  var name: String

  init(_ name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

let p1 = Person("Umair")
let p2 = Person("Ali")


class Container {
  var people = [Person]()

  init(people: [Person]) {
    self.people = people
  }
}

let arr1 = Container(people: [p1, p2])
let arr2 = arr1

print(arr1.people)
print(arr2.people)

arr1.people.removeFirst()

print(arr1.people)
print(arr2.people)
```

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful.

Comment: "virtue of swift" what?? How is that virtue? I don't want to wrap my arrays in classes, that's going to screw up my existing code design. I want to explicitly store a reference counted pointer to that array. In c++ I can easily do that by copying a smart pointer, or if I want, I can do a memcpy.

Comment: Arrays being value types is a virtue of Swift (and Functional Programming). Why, because it eliminates side effects. A value type can not be changed. It simplifies its chain of data processing (everything becomes only local). It simplifies debugging. I don't have to make assumptions about other modules (they have their own copies).

Preferring value types is a virtue because the compiler can apply more optimizations to the compiled code (especially compared to untyped variables like `ID` in Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you're using Swift, you can still use [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray).

Per Apple's documentation,

> NSArray is an object representing a static ordered collection, for use instead of an Array constant in cases that require reference semantics.

The only downside is you'll have to `import Foundation`. This isn't a problem if you're creating an iOS or Mac app, as you're depending on it already.